# Is tree-shaking happening in angular 8 development mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, tree-shaking

I just want to know, if tree-shaking takes place in angular 8 development mode?

When using below command:

> ng build

I know if I use the command below tree-shaking takes place.

> ng build --optimization=true|false

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of Angular: optimization is fault by default.
For the configuration, you can look at your `angular.json` file in projects > project-name > architect > build

Comment: I know those configuration very well. i just want to ensure if i didn't change any configuration, will tree-shaking takles place in dev mode or not?. this is my question